# Negating typescript types?

Tags: typescript, negation

I wanted to create a simple NOT operator in typescript where you get all primitives combined into the union of some type A that are NOT primitive members of the union of a second type B. This can be done using conditional types. For example, if you have types:

```
type A = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type B = 'c' | 'd' | 'e';
```

... then I want to map them to a third derived type [A - B] that, in this case, would yield:

```
type C = 'a' | 'b'
```

This seems to be doable using conditionals of the form shown below. HOWEVER, I am completely stumped why the NOT operator below seems to give me what I want, but explicitly spelling out the exact same conditional logic does not:

```
type not_A_B_1 = A extends B ? never : A;   // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type Not<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;   
type not_A_B_2 = Not<A, B>                  // 'a' | 'b'
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%20%7C%20'c'%3B%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20'c'%20%7C%20'd'%20%7C%20'e'%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20not_A_B_1%20%3D%20A%20extends%20B%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20A%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%20%7C%20'c'%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Not%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20U%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%3B%20%20%20%0D%0Atype%20not_A_B_2%20%3D%20Not%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Could someone pls tell me if I'm missing some TS subtlety here that would explain why `not_A_B_1` and `not_A_B_2` are not equivalent? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've run into [distributive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types):

> Conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter are called *distributive conditional types*. Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`

So in this:

```
type not_A_B_1 = A extends B ? never : A;   // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

The `A` is a concrete type, not a type parameter, so the conditional type *does not* get distributed over its constituents.

But in

```
type Not<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

the `T` is a naked type parameter, so the conditional type *does* get distributed. What does "naked" mean?  It means `T` as opposed to some type function of `T`.  So in `{foo: T} extends W ? X : Y`, the type parameter `T` is "clothed", so it doesn't distribute.

This leads to a way to turn off distributive conditional types when you don't want them: clothe the type parameter.  The simplest and least verbose way to do this is to use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of one element:  So,

```
T extends U ? V : W // naked T
[T] extends [U] ? V : W // clothed T
```

Since `[T] extends [U]` should be true exactly when `T extends U`, those are equivalent except for the distributivity.  So let's change `Not<>` to be non-distributive:

```
type NotNoDistribute<T, U> = [T] extends [U] ? never : T;   
type not_A_B_2 = NotNoDistribute<A, B>                  // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Now `not_A_B_2` is the same as `not_A_B_1`.  If you prefer the original `not_A_B_2` behavior, then use distributive conditional types like `Not<>`.  If you prefer the undistributive behavior, use concrete types or clothed type parameters.  Does that make sense?

By the way, your `Not<T,U>` type is already present as a [predefined type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types) in the standard library as [`Exclude<T,U>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1386-L1389), meant to "exclude from `T` those types that are assignable to `U`".

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Why does `Exclude<any, Excluded>` not work? The `Excluded` is still allowed. It seems to only work if the `any` is replaced with something specific.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have arbitrary negated types; `Exclude<T, U>` only filters unions in `T`.  The type `any` is not a union so it doesn't do anything.